# Pandas join two dataframes with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I want to join two dataframes together, both dataframes have date columns (`df1[date1]`, `df2[date2]`). I want the joined dataframe to satisfy this condition `df2[date2] > df1[date1]`. Second dataframe does not have any duplicates but first one does, so this does not work as expected:

I know for certain that for every date in df2 there is a date in df1 which satisfies this condition. But I cannot figure out how to join them properly. I have tried doing this:

```
joined = df1.join(df2, how='inner')
joined = joined.query('date2 > date1')
```

But since df1 has entries with duplicate id-s the way they align after join results in bunch of rows not satisfying the condition, so I get left with smaller database.
 How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I see here 2 separate tasks: filtering and joining. Tell us precisely how you see each of them performed. In particular, I am confused with condition `df2[date2] > df1[date1]`. is it 'greater than any date1' or 'greater than date1 with the same row index'?

Comment: @Ruslan, greater than date1 with same id is what I am looking for. I want to join two dataframes (on id) so that date2 from df2 is greater than date1 in df1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your clairification I sugegst the following solution:

1) `concatenate` (not `join`) the 2 dataframes.

```
df12 =  pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

I assume that the indices match. If not - reindex on id or `join` on id.

2) filter the rows that match criteria

```
df12 = df12[df12['date2'] > df12['date1]]
```